# Heart Rate data from Apple Watch terribly inaccurate

Tags: ios, sensors, apple-watch, healthkit

I have an iOS fitness app that collects heart rate data from a Bluetooth chest strap. I recently added an Apple Watch extension and tapped into the watch's heart rate sensor as an alternative to a chest strap. Unfortunately, I've found that it's so inaccurate as to be basically useless. Here's an example of a 3-mile hike where the red line shows the data collected from the chest strap and the blue line shows the data collected from the Apple Watch:

[image: watch versus chest strap chart]

I can tell the chest strap data is the more accurate of the two, because when overlaid on the elevation data, the higher heart rates very closely correspond to the uphill sections. (Also, I wouldn't expect my heart rate to jump from 60 to 120 or 110 to 160 as shown by the Apple Watch ... nor to sit at the same value for a minute at a time.)

Here's the code I'm using to collect the watch data. Is there another way to configure this to get more accurate data, or is this as good as it gets with this hardware?

```
- (void)startWorkoutSession {
    if (self.workoutSession) {
        return;
    }

    // configure a HealthKit workout
    HKWorkoutConfiguration *configuration = [[HKWorkoutConfiguration alloc] init];
    configuration.activityType = HKWorkoutActivityTypeHiking;
    configuration.locationType = HKWorkoutSessionLocationTypeOutdoor;

    // start the workout
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.workoutSession = [[HKWorkoutSession alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration error:&error];
    if (!self.workoutSession) {
        //NSLog(@"*** Unable to create the workout session: %@ ***", error.localizedDescription);
        NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            @"createWorkoutSession", @"error",
            error.localizedDescription, @"description",
        nil];
        [self.iosApp sendMessage:data replyHandler:nil errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            // maybe show a local alert here?
        }];
        return;
    }
    self.workoutSession.delegate = self;
    [self.healthStore startWorkoutSession:self.workoutSession];

    // update the controls view and show the tracking view
    self.controls.status = StatusStarted;
    if (![self.activeController isEqual:self.tracking]) {
        [self.tracking becomeCurrentPage];
    }
}

- (void)workoutSession:(HKWorkoutSession *)workoutSession didChangeToState:(HKWorkoutSessionState)toState fromState:(HKWorkoutSessionState)fromState date:(NSDate *)date {
    // required method
    if (toState == HKWorkoutSessionStateRunning) {
        [self requestHeartRate:date];
    }
}

- (void)requestHeartRate:(NSDate *)date {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:date endDate:nil options:HKQueryOptionNone];
    HKSampleType *heartRateType = [HKSampleType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];
    HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query = [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc] initWithType:heartRateType predicate:predicate anchor:0 limit:0 resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query, NSArray<HKSample *> *samples, NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> *deletedObjects, HKQueryAnchor *anchor, NSError *error) {
        if ((!error)&&(samples.count > 0)) {
            [weakSelf receiveHeartRate:(HKQuantitySample *)[samples objectAtIndex:0]];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error with initial heart rate query: %@", error);
        }
    }];
    [query setUpdateHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query, NSArray<HKSample *> *samples, NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> *deletedObjects, HKQueryAnchor *anchor, NSError *error) {
        if ((!error)&&(samples.count > 0)) {
            [weakSelf receiveHeartRate:(HKQuantitySample *)[samples objectAtIndex:0]];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error with updated heart rate query: %@", error);
        }
    }];
    [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];
}

- (void)receiveHeartRate:(HKQuantitySample *)sample {
    HKQuantity *quantity = sample.quantity;
    int value = (int)[quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit unitFromString:@"count/min"]];
    //NSLog(@"got heart rate %i", value);

    // display the heart rate in the tracking view
    [self.tracking updateHeartRate:value];
}
```

**Update:**

I was looking at [this comparison chart](https://9to5mac.com/2015/05/08/apple-watch-heart-rate-monitor-accuracy/) as an indication of the accuracy I should expect from the Apple Watch. Now I realize that's only comparing the Apple Watch to another watch-based (wrist) sensor. So perhaps that chart is just showing that both wrist-based models are similarly inaccurate.

It's confusing because you can search the web for "Apple watch heart rate accuracy" and find lots of stories about how accurate it is, but nobody is showing results like I'm seeing, which I consider to be pretty poor.

Comment: BTW I had the watch strapped on quite tight for this test.

Comment: Wrist-based heart monitors are always going to be less accurate than chest-worn models. Only Apple can make the raw data better but you might try using a running average of the last N measurements instead of using raw values directly.

Comment: @TomHarrington, great idea. I tried as much as a 5 minute rolling average on my test data, but sadly the displayed values were still off by 25-50 bpm for minutes at a time. Shorter periods resulted in data that basically matched the raw watch data. I think that approach would work better to clean up occasional outliers, rather than data like this that's more often wrong than right.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing your app can do to increase heart rate reporting frequency and accuracy on Apple Watch is to record a workout session with an accurate `HKWorkoutActivityType`. Since it looks like you're already doing this, you should [file a radar](https://bugreporter.apple.com) with Apple about the accuracy of the measurements.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Apple Watch 2 is the same. It's extremely inaccurate: it shows 70 right after 90 when I am climbing the stairs for 5 minutes, or it reports unreadably high readings at low intensity exercise. But the most annoying thing is that it periodically loses the heart rate altogether even during walking!

I should have probably waited till generation 4 or 5. Still AW2 is no alternative to Polar HRMs. It's a shame Apple can't provide consistent accuracy of heart rate measurement.